# Highcharts button at hide/show multiple series at once

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to add a button to my page that would hide/show multiple series at once. I know I can do some of that in Highcharts using the legend, but here I'm trying to do that with a button.

Here's the fiddle of the code I'm working on:
https://jsfiddle.net/ssoj_tellig/o1ckqvg4/11/

Many thanks for your help!

```
var mydates = [1527465600000,1528070400000,1528675200000,1529280000000,1529884800000,1530489600000,1531094400000,1531699200000,1532304000000,1532908800000,1533513600000,1534118400000];

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
              
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    type: 'spline',
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: mydates,
    labels:{
      formatter: function() { 
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y', 
                                     this.value); 
      },
      align: 'right',
      rotation: -90,
    },
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 250,
    tickInterval: 50,
    title: {
      text: 'Score'
    }
  },

  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },

  credits :  {
    enabled : false
  },

  navigator :{
    enabled: true
  },

  scrollbar :{
    enabled: true
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'sample1',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
    {
    name: 'sample2',
    data: [45,88, 134.4, 178.2, 125.0, 76.0, 35.6, 48.5, 116.4, 94.1, 195.6, 154.4]},
    {
    name: 'sample3',
    data: [10,38, 104.4, 78.2, 95.0, 56.0, 135.6, 148.5, 96.4, 194.1, 115.6, 114.4]
  }],

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 1
      },
    }
  },

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 1000
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }
});

document.getElementById('#button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  var series = chart.series[0];
  var series1 = chart.series[1];
  if (series.visible & series1.visible) {
    series.hide();
    series1.hide();
    e.target.innerHTML = 'Show sample 1 & 2';
  } else {
    series.show();
    series1.show();
    e.target.innerHTML = 'Hide sample 1 & 2';
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you almost get it, but there was a small mistake, define:

`document.getElementById('button')` instead of `document.getElementById('#button')`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lgrsu2w6/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine if you fix the button query selector? `document.getElementById('button')` instead of `document.getElementById('#button')`

Answer (score 0):

Check this. I add an event as documentation says via

```
Highcharts.addEvent(chart, 'load', someFunction);
```

Check [enter link description here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)

I change the Id with querySelector. In the code below change the classname of highcharts-series-xx wherether xx is the number of series ie 0 or 1 or 2.

```js
var mydates = [1527465600000,1528070400000,1528675200000,1529280000000,1529884800000,1530489600000,1531094400000,1531699200000,1532304000000,1532908800000,1533513600000,1534118400000];

var elm=document.querySelector('button');



const chart_1 = Highcharts.chart('container', {
              
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    type: 'spline',
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: mydates,
    labels:{
      formatter: function() { 
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y', 
                                     this.value); 
      },
      align: 'right',
      rotation: -90,
    },
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 250,
    tickInterval: 50,
    title: {
      text: 'Score'
    }
  },

  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },

  credits :  {
    enabled : false
  },

  navigator :{
    enabled: true
  },

  scrollbar :{
    enabled: true
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'sample1',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
    {
    name: 'sample2',
    data: [45,88, 134.4, 178.2, 125.0, 76.0, 35.6, 48.5, 116.4, 94.1, 195.6, 154.4]},
    {
    name: 'sample3',
    data: [10,38, 104.4, 78.2, 95.0, 56.0, 135.6, 148.5, 96.4, 194.1, 115.6, 114.4]
  }],

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 1
      },
    }
  },
  

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 1000
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }
});

Highcharts.addEvent(chart_1, 'load', 
elm.addEventListener('click', e => {
a=document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-series-1');    
a[0]. remove();
a[1]. remove();
a[2]. remove();

}

));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<button id="button_1" style="width:100px;height:50px">Click to erase</button>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px">  
  
</div>
```

And [JS Fiddle url example](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lnezjkf/)